# How to get sound output device ID

Tags: c#, naudio

I am using `NAudio` to play an mp3 file in my WinForms app. However, the file needs to be played to user-selected device, not the windows default one. So, what I am doing now is loading all available devices using this code:

```
  {
  ManagementObjectSearcher mo =
  new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_SoundDevice");

        foreach (ManagementObject soundDevice in mo.Get())
        {
            String name = soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
            comboBox1.Items.Add(name);
        } 
    }
```

Now, NAudio requires some Device ID to change the active device. How do I get this ID, using the input from the comboBox (the device name)?

Comment: IIRC, NAudio uses the olden device ID passed to waveOutOpen(), a simple sequence number counting from 0 to waveOutGetNumDevs() - 1.  Without an enumerator that allowed identifying the device, this was before plug & play.  You might get lucky and get the devices ordered by number.

Comment: OK, I have tried few things in my code and I would like to chage my question a bit... Is this the correct way to loop the devices? Because no matter which one I choose and get its combobox index, it still plays to the same device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using NAudio and with WaveOut, you can get the device names like this:

```
for (int deviceId = 0; deviceId < WaveOut.DeviceCount; deviceId++)
{
    var capabilities = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(deviceId);
    comboBoxWaveOutDevice.Items.Add(capabilities.ProductName);
}
```

The one caveat is that the old waveOut APIs don't allow for product names with more than 31 characters so they can appear truncated. If this turns out to be a problem for you, then DirectSoundOut or WasapiOut might be a good alternative.